# Rails undefined method `Graphic_Store' for Graphic:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three files, two class files and one module file, the module containing classes that inherit from the other files, that way you can just 'require "graphic"' But it's not working.

the code for the module is

```
require 'gstore'
require 'grender'
require 'chunky_png'
module Graphic

   class Graphic_Store < GStore
   end

   class Graphic_Render < GRender
   end

end
```

I'm not sure if that's how you're supposed to use it but I'm getting undefined method error in the browser. 
It doesn't matter if I do 'Graphic_Store' or Graphic::Graphic_Store' in the controller, I get the same error, only difference is that on the second one it errors on the graphic file rather then the controller.

the only reason I'm doing it this way is becuase it was saying 'undefined method' on them any way, at least this way it's on one file, that and it gives me a name space.

I also keep getting 'unable to load file -chunky_png' when I put the the require in the other files. Doing 'gems' show that the chunky_png gem is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working by removing module and just nesting the two classes inside a Class called Graphic.